# Is there a general way to be notified of all touches began and moved at the UIViewController level?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, uislider, uiresponder

I have a `UIViewController` subclass whose view has a complex hierarchy of descendant views, including `UIButton`s and a `UISlider`. I want to hide the controls after 5 seconds have passed without any user interaction. The 5 seconds part is easy: use a timer. I don't know of a general way to detect user interaction though.

My first thought was to override `UIResponder`'s `touchesBegan:withEvent:` and `touchesMoved:withEvent:` in the `UIViewController` subclass, but those don't get called when the user taps a `UIButton` or drags the knob on the `UISlider`.

What I don't want to do is register for notifications from every control, if I can help it. I also don't want to mess with the `UIWindow`. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up creating a continuous gesture recognizer that recognizes when there is at least one touch. I added it to the UIViewController subclass's view and it works great! It took me a long time to realize that it needed both `cancelsTouchesInView` and `delaysTouchesEnded` set to `false` or else it would fail one way or another.

```
class TouchDownGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer {

    override init(target: AnyObject, action: Selector) {
        super.init(target: target, action: action)

        cancelsTouchesInView = false
        delaysTouchesEnded = false
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
        state = .Began
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
        if numberOfTouches() - touches.count == 0 {
            state = .Ended
        }
    }

    override func touchesCancelled(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
        if numberOfTouches() - touches.count == 0 {
            state = .Cancelled
        }
    }

    override func shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer(otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer!) -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    override func shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer(otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer!) -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    override func canPreventGestureRecognizer(preventedGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer!) -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    override func canBePreventedByGestureRecognizer(preventingGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer!) -> Bool {
        return false
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a UIGestureRecognizer to your UIViewController by calling setupTapGesture in viewDidLoad

```
- (void)setupTapGesture 
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(toggleVisibility)];
    tapGesture.delegate = self;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
}
```

And then use this callback to detect touches from button, sliders (UIControl)

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer    shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch 
{
        //To ignore touches from Player Controls View
        if ([[touch.view superview] isKindOfClass:[UIControl class]]) 
        {
            return NO;
        }
        return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this put me on the right road. I never did get it working with just `gestureRecognizer: shouldReceiveTouch:`, but a custom gesture recognizer did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `UIGestureRecognizer`?. You might have to set up a few different ones for different possible interaction types like holds and swipes, but then you could have all of them call the same function that keeps the screen on and resets the timer.